# Join table to value linked to closest date

Tags: sql, join

I am struggling with this problem in SQL server. So I have two tables:

TableA:

| ID_A | ID_B | Donation_date | Donation_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 15/03/2022 | 3000 |
| 1 | 2 | 25/04/2021 | 5000 |

and TableB

| ID_A | ID_B | Expense_date | Expense_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 17/03/2022 | 50000 |
| 1 | 2 | 20/04/2021 | 70000 |
| 1 | 2 | 01/03/2015 | 180000 |

I want to add a column to TableA that contains a reference expense for each ID, based on the closest date to the dates in TableB.

The output would look like this:

| ID_A | ID_B | Donation_date | Donation_amount | Ref_Expense_date | Ref_expense_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 15/03/2022 | 3000 | 17/03/2022 | 50000 |
| 1 | 2 | 25/04/2021 | 5000 | 20/04/2021 | 70000 |

I am almost certain that I have to use join, but not sure how to do it based on the "closest date".
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: please specify which database (rdbms) you are using, and also how to resolve situations where there are two or more rows in TableB with the same Expense_Date

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear enough. I am not sure about your first question (I am a beginner). About the second question, there are no such cases, as TableB was built with another query (it's already aggregated).

Comment: Are you using sql-server, Oracle, postgresql, MySQL, Teradata, or another applicaiton?

Answer (score 2):

I joined the tables by ID_A and ID_B and then organized the date by the smallest difference in dates using `abs`, `datediff`, and `row_number`.

```
select  t.ID_A
       ,t.ID_B
       ,Donation_date
       ,Donation_amount
       ,Ref_Expense_date
       ,Ref_Expense_amount

from   (
        select TableA.ID_A
              ,TableA.ID_B
              ,Donation_date
              ,Donation_amount
              ,Expense_date   as Ref_Expense_date
              ,Expense_amount as Ref_Expense_amount
              ,row_number() over(partition by TableA.ID_A,TableA.ID_B, Donation_date order by abs(datediff(day, Donation_date,Expense_date))) as rn
        from TableA full join TableB on TableB.ID_A = TableA.ID_A and
                                        TableB.ID_B = TableA.ID_B

       ) t
where rn = 1
```

| ID_A | ID_B | Donation_date | Donation_amount | Ref_Expense_date | Ref_Expense_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-03-15 | 3000 | 2022-03-17 | 50000 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-04-25 | 5000 | 2021-04-20 | 70000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=15a1d9b722ab2bfb949fa0b83d9171b5)

Comment: I suggest to include ID_B to the partition by clause, as well, it seems to be part of the join key.